# Ruby on Rails has_many association define custom ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I have run into a problem and can't figure out how to fix it.

I basically have a ModelA that has a has_many relationship with another ModelB. Let's say that ModelB has two attributes. A `created_at` and a `filename`. Now let's say the `created_at` is not actually accurate due to a race condition. However the `filename` contains a timestamp that is accurate. Unfortunately the filename is also inconsistent and extracting and adding the timestamp beforehand is not an option.

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
class ModelA
    has_many: model_bs, order: extracted_timestamp_from_filename.asc

    def extracted_timestamp_from_filename
        #self would ideally be a single model_bs
        extract_timestamp_from_filename(self.filename)
    end
end
```

At least with `order` I don't think this could ever work without having an actual proper timestamp attribute. Is there a way to get this functionality? If there is a way to do this with hooks somehow I haven't found it.

Comment: I don't get your problem. Why you can not just write like this `has_many: modell_bs, order: :updated_at`

Comment: because as I described, the only accurate timestamp I have available is in the filename. Unfortunately the filenames are not consistently named either. So there is just one way to get a valid timestamp - take the filename, extract the timestamp...

Comment: Extract timestamp from filename it's bad idea. In general because ordering it's a simple SQL action and it shouldn't grab all file names and cut timestamp from them. I believe that it's possible to do with some regexp. But why you need such complex ordering. Better is to add to `ModelB` new field `true_timestamp` and order by it. You need just to write a script to generate this field, or you can do it in `rails console`. My idea sounds twisted, but it's still better then ordering by some field that isn't present it SQL table.

Comment: The scenario is not really up to me since it's a legacy system that I only have limited access to. I suppose there is no in code solution for this then.

Comment: What does it means "the filename contains a timestamp"? Can you put some example filenames?

Comment: `iamthefile-20180211-1700-00-001-foo.mp4` @Pablo Extracting the timestamp is the least of my problems...

Comment: You said you have limited access to the db. Can't you (or some dba) create the new field nautgrad suggested and a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a fix but turns out Rails with a MongoDB is actually able to order by strings and it so happens that the files in my example can be ordered like this. However if the filenames have different formats this will still not work. In my example I think I'll get away with it for now.

Thanks.